# java Https request via proxy dropping headers in doTunneling causing 403

Tags: java, https, proxy, header, httpurlconnection

Trying to acccess an API outside the firewall so we are going through a proxy server but the issue is that this causes HttpURLConnection to drop any set request headers for the URL.

Setup is simple

```
    static {
        System.setProperty("java.net.useSystemProxies", "true"); //use proxy on windows machine
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "trust file"); // for SSL
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=", "password");// for SSL
    }
```

Code is as follows

```
    URL obj = new URL(URL);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();//proxy);
    con.setRequestMethod("GET");
    con.setRequestProperty("token","MYTOKEN");
    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
```

The response returns a 403 forbidden error becasue it is n0t getting the set token.  This is not the same as the auth bug which is similar but is due to a specific header i believe.

The issue occurs in HttpURLConnection where the getReponseCode() initiates a connection. It tries to retrieve the inputstream but needs to connect() to do this.

In connect() in DelegateHttpsURLConnection it does a plainConnect() to return the proxy selector, however in that method we get to doTunneling() which is necesary for the proxy.

in that method there are two lines

```
    MessageHeader savedRequests = requests;
    requests = new MessageHeader();
```

this moves the headers you set into a temporary object since they are not meant for the proxy server. it calls proxiedConnect(url, proxyHost, proxyPort, false); and connects to the proxy.

it then goes to sendCONNECTRequest() but now the headers are not present and the call fails.

I have to think that many people are using SSL over proxy for similar services, how is this not a bigger issue?

Tried various permutations of the the calls and also tried -Djdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes="" but I think this has to do with Basic authentication but is a similar issue.

Everything ends up in the same state with the server returning a Forbidden error

Comment: What proxy do you use? Note that some cloud services are protected using TLS fingerprinting which can detect the used ssl library and programming language. Which often means Python based proxies are blocked. So a HTTP 403 could be cause by other reasons and not by a missing header.

Comment: @Robert I dont know what proxy is being used but I can see that the request is going out without the headers.  I can make other external requests over SSL, the issue is when headers are added